# Tennis tournament algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

After a tennis tournament each player was asked how many matches he had.
An athlete can't play more than one match with another athlete.
As an input the only thing you have is the number of athletes and the matches each athlete had. As an output you will have 1 if the tournament was possible to be done according to the athletes answers or 0 if not. For example:

```
Input: 4 3 3 3 3      Output: 1  
Input: 6 2 4 5 5 2 1  Output: 0  
Input: 2 1 1          Output: 1  
Input: 1 0            Output: 0  
Input: 3 1 1 1        Output: 0  
Input: 3 2 2 0        Output: 0  
Input: 3 4 3 2        Output: 0
```

the first number of the input is not part of the athletes answer it's the number of athletes that took part in the tournament for example in 6 2 4 5 5 2 1 we have 6 athletes that took part and their answers were 2 4 5 5 2 1.

So far this is what we wrote but didn't work that great:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Tennis {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String N;
        int count;
        int sum = 0;
        int max;
        int activeAthletes;
        int flag;

        System.out.printf("Give: ");
        N = input.nextLine();

        String[] arr = N.split(" ");
        int[] array = new int[arr.length];

        for (count = 0; count < arr.length; count++) {
            array[count] = Integer.parseInt(arr[count]);
            //System.out.print(arr[count] + " ");
        }

        for (count = 1; count < arr.length; count++) {
            sum += array[count];
        }
        //System.out.println("\n" + sum);

        activeAthletes = array[0];

        for (count = 1; count < array.length; count++) {
            if (array[count] == 0) {
                activeAthletes--;
            }
        }

        max = array[1];
        for (count = 2; count < array.length; count++) {
            if (array[count] > max) {
                max = array[count];
            }
        }
       // System.out.println(max);

        if ((sum % 2 == 0) && (max < activeAthletes)) {            
            flag = 1;
        } else{
            flag = 0;
        }

        System.out.println(flag);
    }
}
```

I do not want a straight solution just maybe some tips and hints because we really have no idea what else to do and I repeat even though I'll tag it as a homework (because I feel the moderators will close it again) it is not, it's just something my brother found and we are trying to solve.

Well many of you have answered and I'm really grateful but as I have work tomorrow I need to go to sleep, so I'll probably read the rest of the answers tomorrow and see what works

Comment: The first thing you should do after you get the number of athletes and the total number of matches is decide whether or not that there is any way for that to be valid. (If there are more matches the total number of possible matches than it's not valid) the total number of possible matches is (I think) `n choose 2 * 2` (accounted for the fact that each match is counted twice once for each person)

Comment: Is this problem for a [Round-robin tournament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament) or [Single-elimination tournament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-elimination_tournament)?

Comment: Sorry your previous question got derailed by trolls.  I'll upvote it hope it doesn't get derailed and closed again.  Looks interesting.

Comment: @JasonBraucht - I'll let the OP respond, but the way I saw it was that it's neither - sort of a possibly incomplete round-robin with no elimination

Comment: yes it is kind of like Round-robin tournament as it seems

Comment: Why is the answer for `1 0` `0`? You say each athlete can't play **more than one match** with another. That implies they can play `0` matches. So can they or can't they play 0 matches?

Comment: is this a programming contest problem? if so, do you have the link to the original problem?

Comment: That is unfortunately not given and as a matter of fact it is quite confusing but the Input: 1 0 Output: 0 is deffinitely correct so I guess they can play 0 matches because another valid point would be that 1 0 is 0 because it only has 1 player, so it is not a valid tournament

Comment: For what it's worth, this is a really interesting and probably more difficult problem than one would initially suspect - at least if I understand your question correctly and you want to decide whether a "tournament" with that number of matches can actually be constructed.

Comment: I asked the math nerds for help on this one if anyone wants to follow http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136994/existence-of-a-binary-symmetric-matrix-from-row-sums

Comment: lol @ "math nerds" - but thanks for the link, the comment there was interesting!

Comment: @IVlad I assume the answer for `0 0` would be `1` and the answer for `1 1` would be `1` but `1 0` should be `0`.  Who is the first player playing if the second player is not playing?

Comment: @emory - you got it wrong. The `1` in `1 0` represents the number of players, not the matches of one of the players. There is only one player who played `0` matches.

Comment: @IVlad You are right.  I read it too fast and missed that.

Comment: @TheByt3: When people request more information, that information goes in the question, not the comments.  Comments can and are deleted without warning, and future visitors will miss out.reported games must be even.

Comment: I am sorry as I was not aware of that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if it works 100%, i would go like:

1. Sort input
2. for each element going from right to left in array (bigger to smaller)

   - based on value n of element at index i decrease n left elements by 1
   - return fail if cant decrease because you reached end of list or value 0
3. return success.

This logic (if correct) can lead whit some modifications to O(N*log(N)) solution, but I currently think that that would be just too much for novice programmer.

**EDIT:**

This does not work correct on input
2 2 1 1

All steps are then (whitout sorting):

1. while any element in list L not 0:

   - find largest element N in list L
   - decrease N other values in list L by 1 if value >= 1 (do not decrease this largest element)

     - return fail if failure at this step
   - set this element N on 0
2. return OK

Comment: This fails for 3 2 2 0 I think

Comment: @spinning_plate - `0 2 2` would cause it to return `0` immediately if I understand correctly.

Comment: that is actually what I had initially planned to do but I didn't like it, I wanted something more mathematical and elegant

Comment: +1, I think this solution is correct, but I'd love to see a proof

Comment: I was thinking about the same solution and I think it works (The array needs to be resorted after step 2). Anybody can think of an exception?

Comment: Am I missing something or does this still fail on `4 2 2 1 1`? Wouldn't you do: `1 1 2 2 -> 0 0 2 2 -> no solution`? There is a solution though: `1 1 2 2` - p1 plays p3 => `0 1 1 2` - p2 plays p4 => `0 0 1 1` - p3 plays p4 => game end.

Comment: You're missing something I think, 4 2 2 1 1 works with what ralu suggested.

Comment: I think this part is confusing: `decrease n left non zero elements elements`. It implies the `n` left non-zero elements are taken from the left of the array, not the left of the current element. If taken from the current element, then it does indeed work.

Comment: I Vlad i think that current solution is better, but not sure if correct.

Comment: @ralu: Did I read this correctly, you think you have an example for which the algorithm doesn't work correctly? That would surprise me because if I did not make a mistake, I think the answer I just posted contains an (informally written) proof of why your algorithm works correctly.

Comment: @deathApril Looking forward to that condition; I'd also be interested in an efficient way to check for it since I have a hunch of what you could be thinking of and can't solve it myself.

Comment: I found an equivalent problem with proof that looks a lot like your solution. The only difference is that the list gets sorted (this affects the assignments, possibly) See my answer

Comment: @G.Bach my attempt for O(n) did not pass the tests, i was thinking about this condition `min_data >= sum_data / count_players - 1`

Comment: @deathApril I don't see why you would compare against min_data instead of max_data, could you ellaborate?

Comment: @ralu: The edited version tries to get rid of the necessity for sorting but fails the crucial part of the reduction, which is to always take the N highest values; without sorting, you'd have to potentially iterate N² times through the array to get them in each iteration, bringing the costs for the reduction to O(n³) since you potentially need n - 1 iterations. (see next comment as well)

Comment: (..)Also, could you illustrate for those curious - including me :) - which modifications you had in mind to get O(n log n)? The way I see it, you need O(n²) for all iterations of the reduction (n iterations times O(n) for the reducation in each iteration) and O(n log n) for sorting the subarray that's left after each iteration, bringing it to a total of O(n (n + n log n)) = O(n² log n).

Comment: @G.Bach i tried both,, i found out that if either `max(data)/sum(data)/count_players > 0.1` or `min(data)/sum(data)/count_players > 0.625` is true (besides all Li-aung Yip's conditions), than the tournament is possible (i don't know how to prove it, but i tested it on 10 000s of pseudorandom tournaments - so if my generator doesn't have a sense of humor, its a solid rule)

Comment: @deathApril How'd you work out whether the tournaments you construct are valid? Also, how'd you get the thresholds 0.1 and 0.625? That's a tenth and five eighths, so you probably had a purpose behind that. Would you maybe update your answer below with more detail? I'd like to see which algorithms work for this method and have something to work with to think about why they work (I'm usually more interested in the Why than in the How anyway). Do you have an O()-runtime for your way to check the tournament for validity?

Comment: ralu's way without the edit deffinitely works for 4 2 2 1 1 because you have: 2 2 1 1 -> 1 1 2 2 -> 1 0 1 0 -> 0 0 1 1 -> 0 0 0 0. @ralu I am implementing you solution right now and I will inform if it works

Comment: @G.Bach i compared my results with ralu's algorithm (the one with sorting) and i tested the differences by hand (for tournamens with less than 10 players) - but i see i forgot to mention - if both my new conditions were False, i couldn't think of other O(n) conditions :(

Comment: @TheByt3 You can be sure ralu's suggestion works, there's a paper that proved that approach for exactly this kind of problem to work correctly. So should you implement it and find it to make mistakes, you would have implemented it wrong (which is a good thing! Knowing where the problem must be is a first step towards solving a problem)

Comment: @deathApril Could you please post all the conditions you used in an answer, with all necessary parentheses?

Comment: @G.Bach oh,, i didn't save it yesterday since it was a dead end :( but if you think it is worth reconstructing, i will have a look at it later..

Answer (score 5):

Here's a hint. Answer these questions

1. Given N athletes, what is the maximum number of matches?
2. Given athlete X, what is the maximum number of matches he could do?
3. Is this sufficient to check just these?  If you're not sure, try writing a program to generate every possible matching of players and check if at least one satisfies the input.  This will only work for small #s of atheletes, but it's a good exercise.  Or just do it by hand

Another way of asking this question, can we create a symmetric matrix of 1s and 0s whose rows are equal the values.  This would be the table of 'who played who'.  Think of this like an N by N grid where grid[i][j] = grid[j][i] (if you play someone they play you) and grid[i][i] = 0 (no one plays themselves)

For example

```
Input: 4 3 3 3 3 Output: 1
```

Looks like

```
 0 1 1 1
 1 0 1 1
 1 1 0 1
 1 1 1 0
```

We can't do this with this one, though:
    Input: 3 2 2 0 Output: 0

***EDIT***

This is equivalent to this  (from [Degree (graph theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28graph_theory%29))

> Hakimi (1962) proved that *(d1, d2, ..., dn)* is a degree sequence of a
>   simple graph if and only if *(d2 − 1, d3 − 1, ..., dd1+1 − 1, dd1+2,
>   dd1+3, ..., dn)* is. This fact leads to a simple algorithm for finding
>   a simple graph that has a given realizable degree sequence:
>
> 1. Begin with a graph with no edges.
> 2. Maintain a list of vertices whose degree requirement has not yet been met in non-increasing order of residual degree requirement.
> 3. Connect the first vertex to the next *d1* vertices in this list, and then remove it from the list. Re-sort the list and repeat until all
>      degree requirements are met.
>
> The problem of finding or estimating the number of graphs with a given
>   degree sequence is a problem from the field of [graph enumeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_enumeration).

Comment: I like (1) and (2), but (3) checking by brute force doesn't sit right with me ;) I really do like how you suggest thinking about the problem in terms of a symmetric matrix, but given the OP's level of computer science (grade school) it might be appropriate to explain further what a "symmetric matrix" is, and possibly give an example. (Remember the diagonal must be zeroes.)

Comment: @Li-aungYip - re: (3) this is what I do when I get stuck :) Not as a solution, just to check my intuitions

Comment: I'm actually into college and I know what a symmetric matrix is actually

Comment: I am really sorry, it's just that English is not my native language. I will try to improve this in the future

Comment: Link to the original paper by Hakimi for those interested: http://compalg.inf.elte.hu/~tony/Oktatas/Algoritmusok-hatekonysaga/Hakimi-SIAM62.pdf

Comment: Actually, I would suggest using the equation given by the Erdős–Gallai theorem (see the wiki-link as well) since it eliminates the need to re-sort after every iteration, making it possible to simple check whether that equation holds for all nodes.

Comment: Oh, because I didn't read the paper by Hakimi carefully enough yesterday to give an exact quote: the relevant proof for this problem starts on page 502 (= page 8 of the pdf) and is the proof regarding "realizability as a graph without parallel elements" by which Hakimi means realizability as a simple graph (i.e. without parallel edges). That proof implies exactly the test algorithm Kirill Yunussov and ralu proposed.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can take the array of athletes' match qties, and determine the largest number in there.

Then see if you can split that number into 1's and subtract those 1's from a few other members of the array.

Zero out that largest number array member, and remove it from the array, and update the other members with reduced values.

Now, repeat the process - determine the new largest number, and subtract it from other members of the array.

If at any point there are not enough array members to subtract the 1's from, then have the app return 0.  otherwise continue doing it until there are no more members in the array, at which point you can have the app return 1.

Also, remember to remove array members that were reduced down to zero.

Comment: that is exactly what I have been doing by hand to determine if the match quantity was valid or not but I didn't want to implement this in an algorithm because it seemed the easiest way as of thinking and hardest way as of implementing into a programming language that's why I wanted a "smarter" solution

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Below solution passes some invalid inputs as valid. It's a fast way to check for definite negatives, but it allows false positives.

---

Here's what a mathematician would suggest:

1. The sum of the number of matches must be even. `3 3 4 2 1` sums to `13`, which would imply someone played a match against themselves.
2. For `n` players, if every match eliminates one player at least `n-1` distinct matches must be played. (A knockout tournament.) To see this, draw a tree of matches for 2, 4, 8, 16, 32... players, requiring 1, 3, 7, 31... matches to decide a winner.
3. For `n` players, the maximum number of matches if everyone plays everyone once, assuming no repeat matches, is `n choose 2`, or `(n!)/(2!)(n-2)!` (Round robin tournament). `n!` is the factorial function, `n! = n * n-1 * n-2 * ... * 3 * 2 * 1.`.

So the criteria are:

1. Sum of the number of matches must be even.
2. Sum of the number of matches must be at least `2n-2`. (Note the multiplication by 2 - each match results in **both** players increasing their count by one.)
3. Sum of the number of matches must be at most `2 * n choose 2`.
4. [Edit] Each player must participate in at least one match.

If your tournament is a cross between a knockout tournament and a round robin tournament, you could have somewhere between `n-1` and `n choose 2` matches.

Edit:

If any player plays more than `n-1` matches, they played someone at least twice.

If your tournament is a knockout tournament ordered so that each player participates in as few matches as possible, then each player can participate in at most `log_2(n)` matches or so (Take `log` base 2 and round up.) In a tournament with 16 players, at most 4 matches. In a tournament of 1024 players, at most 10 matches.

Comment: I believe that is exactly it. We had tracked down the first 2 criteria but we couldn't find the third one and I was sure it was something along those lines. I will test it today or tomorrow and let you know if it worked

Comment: no the only limitation is that a player can't have more than one match with another player

Comment: I don't see how you arrive at the second condition. From the way he stated the problem, I assume 2 0 0 would be valid input.

Comment: @G.Bach : That input reads as : "Player A played in two matches, player B played in no matches, and player C played in no matches". (Who did player A play against? ;) )

Comment: I taught that round robin equation is same as number of diagonals of polygon -> (n² - 3n)/2

Comment: The input reads as "2 players played; player 1 played 0 matches; player 2 played 0 matches".

Comment: @G.Bach : ah, missed that part of the question. Nonetheless, condition  2 remains logically valid: if two players participate in zero matches, then there isn't a winner. (We're assuming there's a winner, right?)

Comment: Why would we assume that? The way I understand the question is, is there a way a tournament with those specifications can actually have taken place, in other words, is there a directed graph with nodes having the degrees of the nodes matching the number of matches each player played and with the given number of players matching that of the nodes. I can't see a problem related to deciding a winner in OP's question.

Comment: @ralu: not quite right. You actually want `(n^2 - n)/2`. (Consider your expression tells you that two players (`n=2`) will participate in `-0.50` matches.)

Comment: @ralu It's not a polygon you want for a round robin but a complete undirected graph, getting the number Li-aung Yip posted.

Comment: `6 => 2 4 5 5 2 2` is not possible, but the sum (20) fulfills all your conditions

Comment: @deathApril: in what particular way is that not valid?

Comment: @Li-aungYip, Wikipedia gives `n/2 (n-1)` as the number of matches in their [round-robin scheduling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm).  I'm not a mathematician :) so I'm not sure I understand why you suggested `n choose 2` instead.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @JasonBraucht: Because I had my mathematician hat on and I was thinking about it combinatorically (`n choose k`), not in terms of 'number of edges in complete undirected graph'. In this case, `n choose 2 == n!/2!(n-2!)` which simplifies to `(n^2 -n)/2` which is the same thing.

Comment: @Li-aungYip And what would graph theory be if not a discipline of math?

Comment: @G.Bach: After attempting to draw the graph for [6][2, 3, 3, 5, 1, 1] I now see why it's impossible. Looks like you actually do have to solve a graph problem after all. (I was hoping for an `O(1)` solution...)

Comment: @Li-aungYip It is a graph problem (see my answer for a somewhat formalistic formulation of the problem and an algorithm that tries to solve it); you actually only have to check a subset (n(n-1) choose (sum of matches/2)) graphs to check whether a valid solution exists, the subset being those graphs that have nodes with the degress described by the input. Still hard for large number of players though; imagine it has 10 players and a total of 30 games - that's more than 3*10^11 graphs we would have to check for matching the given input if we try the trivial approach of checking all combinations.

Comment: @Li-aungYip just in case you care - it's not O(1), but O(n) because of sum(array)...

Answer (score 0):

Your examples can all trivially be solved by counting the matches and looking whether they divide by 2.

A problem not covered by your examples would be a player, who has more games than the sum of the other players:

- Input: 4 5 1 1 1 Output: 0

This can be complicated if we add more players:

- Input: 6 5 5 5 1 1 1 Output: 0

How to solve this question? Well, remove one game pairwise from the maximum and the minimum player, and see what happens:

- Input: 6 5 5 5 1 1 1
- Input: 5 5 5 4 1 1 -
- Input: 4 5 4 4 1 - -
- Input: 3 4 4 4 - - -

It violates the rule:

> An athlete can't play more than one match with another athlete.

If 3 players are left, they can't have had more than 2 games each.